# Android: Custom Parcelable Class Crashes App Without Throwing Exception

Tags: java, android, android-activity, arraylist, parcelable

I've got an Android app with custom objects which implement the Parcelable interface. They way I have it set it up is that my program initially creates an `ArrayList` of a custom class `Products` from a file in the bundle. I can see and confirm that the arraylist and it's instance variabels are populated appropriately. This class has several instance variables along with one being another `ArrayList` but with the `String` class. Remember that fact.

I am trying to pass the `ArrayList<Product>` into a new activity like so:

```
  try {
         Intent i = new Intent(RootActivity.this, ProductsActivity.class);     //Intent from this activity to the next
         i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Products", app_products);              //Puts my ArrayList<Class A> as an extra
         startActivity(i);                                                     //Launch the activity

       }
       catch(Exception e){
           Log.d("Activity Error", "Error Here:" + e.getMessage());
       }
```

I am collecting the information back from the intent in my new activity by pulling the `ArrayList` out by using

```
     app_products = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("Products");
```

For my custom class, it looks something like this, along with the implemented Parcelable methods.

```
public class Product implements Parcelable{
      private String name;
      private String cost;
      private ArrayList<String> similarItems;

      public Product{
            name = null;
            cost = null;
            similarItems = new ArrayList<String>();
      }

     public Product(String name, String cost){
            this();
            this.name = name;
            this.cost = cost;
     }

     public addSimilarItem(String item){
            similarItems.add(item);
     }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Product> CREATOR
        = new Parcelable.Creator<Product>()
    {
         public Product createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
               return new Product(in);
         } 

         public Product[] newArray(int size) {
               return new Product[size];
         }
    };

    public int describeContents(){
          return 0;
    }

    private Product(Parcel in){
         name = in.readString();
         cost = in.readString();
         similarItems = in.readArrayList(String.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags){
         out.writeString(name);
         out.writeString(cost);
         out.writeList(similarItems);
    }
}
```

So this works well **WITHOUT** my String arraylist being added in the class

Comment out `out.writeList(similarItems);` and also `similarItems = in.readArrayList(String.class.getClassLoader());`

but once you add them back in into the class, the app crashes but it doesn't even throw a message for debugging. I've wrapped everything around `try-catch` statements and android doesn't even report the app crashed with the normal dialog on the springboard. I am truly at a loss.

It is worth mentioning that I've used some log statements to understand where the program is crashing despite the fact that android wont throw an exception. I can see that all of the items in my ArrayList undergoes the writeToParcelMethod and completes writing. The Product(Parcel in) method is never called. Lastly, I can also see the class I am launching the new activity from enters the `Pause State` and my new Activity is never created.

Let me know if I can provide any additional information.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/247842d49577607c77d9.git

Comment: I've been having same issue man

Answer (score 1):

Fairly certain your problem is the use of `writeList()`. `writeList()` seems to indicate that it follows the same contract as `writeValue()` for the items contained in the list. `readList()` however, seems to indicate that the values must be `Parcelable` (which `String` is not).

Either way, typically these calls have to be very specifically linked to their inverse (e.g. `writeString()` must be read in with `readString()`, not `readValue()`) so you should instead use the provided methods for reading/writing `String` `List`s:

```
// Takes in a List<String> which may be null
out.writeStringList(similarItems);

// Returns either null or a new ArrayList<String> with the contents
similarItems = in.createStringArrayList();
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be true for every instance though? I am using this method for hundreds of entries from my XML resource and they all work with the method I have list above except for one. So wouldn't that point to a bad resource entry?

Comment: Yes, it's interesting if it's not causing issues elsewhere. Looking into it further it looks like `writeList` and `readArrayList` should also work properly (although it's not typesafe since it just returns an `ArrayList`). There shouldn't be anything you could put into an `ArrayList<String>` that would cause a crash like that, though. Could you capture a log from the crash and put it elsewhere from Github Gist? It's not loading for me. (Maybe pastebin?)

Answer (score 0):

These seemed to be due to some malformed XML which my app uses as a resource. Not sure why this was this issue but after many hours of hunting it down, I was able to remove the bad XML and will revisit this issue at a later date towards when I need to release the app.

Right now, I'm just gonna worry about continuing to develop it. I'll try to remember to check back here if I find anything interesting about my XML.